# Microsoft/Windows keyboard number pad with macOS

Tags: mac, keyboard, microsoft

I recently purchased a Microsoft keyboard with a number pad.

When trying to use the Mac calculator app with the number pad I have an issue where typing a number will clear out previous numbers.

E.g if I wanted to type "100" in the calculator, I would press <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>. However, the result that shows in the calculator is not 100, but just `0`, because it was the last number I pressed.

Example:

[image: Animated gif of the Calculator app showing the input of the number '100' where the display is only showing the '0']

Are my mappings incorrect and causing this issue?

Using Key Codes to check what each key on the numpad does:

<kbd>1</kbd> on the numpad, seems to provide two key down events:

```
Key Down
     Characters: 
     Unicode:    63289 / 0xf739
     Keys:
     Key Code:   71 / 0x47
     Modifiers:  10486016 / 0xa00100

Key Down
     Characters: 1
     Unicode:    49 / 0x31
     Keys:       #1
     Key Code:   83 / 0x53
     Modifiers:  2097408 / 0x200100
```

Comment: did you check this guide: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-a-numeric-keypad-doesnt-work-mchlp2366/mac ?

Comment: @Ant yes I checked. I don't have a num lock key, I tried pressing shift+delete and it did nothing. I don't have Mouse Keys activated in the a11y settings.

Comment: Did you use the numpad delete button for shit+delete?

Comment: @Ant I don't have a numpad delete button, just "clear". Regardless, shift+clear also does not change anything.

Comment: Did you try a SMC/CMOS reset?

Comment: Get hold of [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) from the App Store & check what is recorded as you press each number. Also, test the 'qwerty' numbers. They should have different codes to those on the numpad. eg qwerty 1 is 18, numpad 1 is 83. You should also check the they key above 7 sends the clear signal (71), not numlock [Mac doesn't know what to do with a numlock key on an extended keyboard, Mac keyboards don't have one]

Comment: BTW, none of this is controlled by SMC or NVRAM [& Mac doesn't have a CMOS]

Comment: @Tetsujin I have added an example of what I see when pressing "1" in Key Codes. Does this look correct? It seems to suggest that I'm pressing two keys when I press just one.

Comment: Now that is very weird. The 'other key', 71, is in fact the 'clear' key. 83 is the correct numpad '1' key. Not sure what else to suggest. Maybe reboot, make the Mac forget the keyboard then reconnect, using System Prefs > Keyboard > Change Keyboard type…

Comment: I grabbed a pretty generic Windows keyboard to test - 1 sends 83 and numlock sends 71, so it is recognised as 'clear' by the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the same problem, and this may work.
Use Karabiner, choose the number pad device and make a Simple modification item from 'keypad_num_lock' to 'vk_none'. This will stop sending key code 71 when taping.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @fat4talk helped me! Great, thank you!

Just go to https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/ to download and install *Karabiner-Elements* as fat4talk proposed. You have to give the software the required rights in newer macOS (you know, **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **General** to allow the Karabiner module and then at the **Privacy** tab to give Karabiner input monitoring rights).

Then open Karabiner-Elements, in **Devices** mark the Microsoft Number Pad active and make the **Simple Modification** ('keypad_num_lock' to 'vk_none')

As long as Microsoft/Apple doesn't solve the problem this workaround is ok but nasty...

I'm using macOS Monterey on a MacBookPro14 M1 with the Microsoft Bluetooth NumPad and Office Excel for Mac v16.56